# Adding paging to ListView using model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview, entity-framework-5

I am using .NET 4.5 and want to add paging to my ListView which is using model binding.

I have Googled and found the answer:

http://dotnet.learningtree.com/2012/11/30/efficient-paging-with-model-binding-in-web-forms/

However as the code snippets are done as images where the author says "When I add a new GetData() method, it creates a stub in the code-behind with an IQueryable..." I cannot see where that is added.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? All I am trying to do is add paging to my ListView that is model bound in an efficient fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside you `<asp:ListView...` tag type `SelectMethod` and you will get a method stub generator helper. If you press TAB it will create a method `ListViewId_GetData` in your code behind. The whole picture:

```
<asp:ListView SelectMethod="ListView1_GetData" ID="ListView1" runat="server">
</asp:ListView>
```

Code-behind:

```
public IQueryable ListView1_GetData()
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That does not explain where the int id, int currentRow, int pageSize parameters come from.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2012, you will see an auto added comment in code behind when you add SelectMethod, that explains everything. Here are the comments: `The return type can be changed to IEnumerable, however to support paging and sorting, the following parameters must be added:
int maximumRows
int startRowIndex
out int totalRowCount`